# read two columns in Excel using python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a python script which should read xlsx file and based on value of column X, it should write/append file with the value of column Z.

Sample data:

```
Column A    Column X    Column Y    Column Z
123     abc     test        value 1
124     xyz     test        value 2
125     xyz     test        value 3
126     abc     test        value 4
```

If value in Column X = abc then it should create a file (if not existing already) in some path with name abc.txt and insert the value of column Z in abc.txt file, likewise if Column X = xyz then it should create a file in same path with xyz.txt and insert the value of column Z in xyz.txt file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsm')
ws = wb.active
for cell in ws.columns[9]:  #here column 9 is value is what i am testing which is Column X of my example.
    if cell.value == "abc":
        print ws.cell(column=12).value  #this is not working and i dont know how to read corresponding value of another column
```

Please suggest what could be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
print ws.cell(column=12).value
```

By:

```
print ws.columns[col][row].value
```

in your case:

```
print ws.columns[12-1][cell.row-1].value
```

**Note** that if you use this indexation method `cols` and `rows` start with index 0. This is why I'm doing `cell.row-1`, so take it into account when you address your column, **if your `12` starts counting from `1` you'll have to address to `11`**.

> Alternatively you can access to your information cell like this: `ws.cell(row = cell.row, column = 12).value`. *Note in this case cols and rows start at 1.*